# Android N change screen brighness very fast - no dimming

Tags: android, toggle, screen, brightness

I am working on the app which toggles between high and low brightness values. The phones I am using are LG G3/G4 on Marshmallow (API 21, 23) and Nexus 5x on Nougat.

This is a code I use for brightness update:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(int brightness) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = (float) brightness / 255; //...and put it here
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        if (DEBUG_MODE) Log.d("activity", "BR ACTIVITY");
    }
```

Everything works great on Marshmallow devices, however the same changes on Nexus are dramatically slower, soem sort of dimming is applied.

Does anybody have a clue how to disable this on Nougat and allow the quick brightness uodates (< 10ms) to happen?

I'd be super thankful for any input.

Comment: Could you track down the problem if it is either the Android version or the device that makes a difference?

Comment: I dont have any other device with Nougat than two pieces of Nexus 5x, both of them representing the same issue.

Comment: I am downgrading one of the  Nexuses to Marshmallow to see if that's hardware or API related.

Comment: Any news regarding the downgrade? Unfortunately I also only own a Nexus 5X with Android Oreo, same problem as you describe.

Comment: Downgraded to Marshmallow, same story... I am afraid it is hardware related, or somewhere deep in the system.